# Nonlinear fitting of a Gaussian beam model

Tags: fitting

I am having some troubles with the NonlinearModelFit function. However hard I try, I cannot get a nice fit curve for the data points. I know the parameter "a" is about 15*10^-6 but even if I plug in the guess parameter I still do not get the fitting. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

```
f[z_] := a*Sqrt[1 + (z)^2/(a^2*Pi/632.8/10^-9)^2];
data = {{0, 8*10^-6}, {2*10^-2, 23*10^-6}, {3*10^-2, 
53*10^-6}, {-3.4*10^-2, 73*10^-6}, {-2*10^-2, 45*10^-6}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[z], {a}, z];
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[{nlm[z]}, {z, -4*10^-2, 4*10^-2}],Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: "even if I plug in the guess parameter" - how did you try to use your guess within `NonlinearModelFit[]`? I do not see it in the code you provided.

Comment: Oh I didn't put it in the code I provided. nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[z], {{a, 10*10^-6}}, z]. But the guess parameter doesn't really do anything. The curve still looks the same.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: If I plot `f[z]` with your suggested initial condition of `a=15*10^(-6)` it does not resemble at all the few data points you provide. Do you maybe have a typo in your definition of `f`? Also: Slightly more data points might improve the fit (this is a general remark)

Comment: Thank you @Lukas! I am pretty sure the definition of f I provided is correct. I unfortunately cannot get more data points at this point.

Comment: But you agree that this (http://imgur.com/dO2Z7ox) does not look right. So I would also propose a different model, or suspect huge errors in your measurement data (guessing it is a measurement - from answers/comments below). Do you have error information? Including these as `Weights` might improve the fit

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the model is not good enough for the data. May be a good idea would be to try a different model, of course if the theory behind does not strictly prescribe this present form. Something along this line, for example:

```
    model1 = a*Sqrt[z^2 + c] + b;
model2 = a*Abs[z + c] + b;
ff1 = FindFit[data, model1, {a, {b, 0}, {c, 0.0001}}, z]
ff2 = FindFit[data, model2, {a, {b, 0}, {c, 0.001}}, z]
Show[{
  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[model1 /. ff1, {z, -0.04, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Plot[model2 /. ff2, {z, -0.04, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> Green]
  }]
```

yielding

[image]

where the red and green lines show the fitting with two close, but slightly different models.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexei! The green curve you worked out actually looks like what my teacher is expecting me to get. However, the model I provide is concrete so I don't think it's possible to try out a different model.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, check the data and the model twice, three times, many times.

Check beam radius and remember: only two parameters need to be specified to give the whole beam profile: the wavelength **Lambda** and the beam waist **w**.

$w \sqrt{\frac{\lambda ^2 z^2}{\pi ^2 w^4}+1}$

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, w*Sqrt[1 + ((\[Lambda]*z)/(\[Pi]*w^2))^2], {w, \[Lambda]}, z]

FittedModel[6.88071*10^-6 Sqrt[1+75065.2 z^2]]

nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> ```
> {w->6.88071*10^-6,\[Lambda]->-4.07508*10^-8}
> ```

```
lp1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

```
p1 = Plot[{nlm[z]}, {z, -0.04, 0.04}]
```

[image]

```
Show[lp1, p1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Louis. This is actually what I did earlier: providing the fit function with 2 parameters, although slightly different (I set the Raleigh length zr = second parameter because \lambda is already known to be 632.8nm for our lab). I got the same curve you did but my teacher's remark was that zr and w are of course not independent parameters and that I should have been able to get a better fit that would look, quite curiously, exactly like the green curve Alexei just worked out below.

Comment: @PhilNguyen, well never ever mess up with your teacher ...

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you meant.